# How can I improve speed of for loops in Google Sheets app script?

Tags: loops, for-loop, google-sheets

I know I must use array to improve speed when use for loop but I don't understand how to do that? How can I rewrite this code?

```
function hiliptk() {
  //var I_INDEX = 1;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i=3; i<=98; i++) {
    var row = sheet.getRange(i, 1, 1,9);
    if (sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue()== "PTK") {
      row.setBackground("yellow");
    } else {row.setBackground("white");}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part of your code `var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();` will return a 2 dimensional array containing the data in your sheets. You can use the 3rd element of each sub-array to check whether it is "PTK" or not.

### Example:

```
function hiliptk() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var dataValues = dataRange.getValues();
  var rangeListYellowBG = [];
  var rangelistWhiteBG = [];

  //this loop collects the range by the value of column C
  for (var i=2; i<dataValues.length; i++){
    if(dataValues[i][2] == 'PTK'){
      //push to array rangeListYellowBG if column C is 'PTK'
      rangeListYellowBG.push("A"+parseInt(i+1)+":I"+parseInt(i+1));
    }else{
      //else push to rangelistWhiteBG
      rangelistWhiteBG.push("A"+parseInt(i+1)+":I"+parseInt(i+1));
    }
  }
  //this will change the background color of the following range to yellow [A5:I5, A8:I8, A11:I11, A12:I12]
  sheet.getRangeList(rangeListYellowBG).setBackground("yellow");
  //this will change the background color of the following range to white [A3:I3, A4:I4, A6:I6, A7:I7, A9:I9, A10:I10, A13:I13]
  sheet.getRangeList(rangelistWhiteBG).setBackground("white");
}
```

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

### References:

- [array.push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)
- [getRangeList()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangelista1notations)